# Will a large number of Task.Delay cause performance problems

Tags: c#, .net

Will a large number of Task.Delay cause performance problems, or is there a better way to replace it when I want to use it to delay delivery of messages to rabbitmq?

I recently wrote an eventbus combined with orleans. When the consumer's consumption is abnormal, I want it to try again several times within 5 minutes to fix the error caused by the short-term system unavailability. I want to use await Task. Delay to implement it, I am not sure if this will affect performance or if there is a better way to implement my idea.

Thanks.

Comment: A large number of *anything* will cause performance problems, however this is likely better than other approaches as it doesn't hold up threads, and works on a timer and call back

Comment: So if send to rabbitmq failed you can retry sending after x seconds for n times. And then assume the connection to be dead and wait for Manual intervention. Continuing to wait and send for longer will achieve nothing but sleeping/waiting threads.

Comment: Can you give a number approximation? "Large number" is too ambiguous.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I understand what you mean i think i should add a circuit breaker.

Comment: @ Prateek Shrivastava thanks for help.

Comment: I still don't know what you mean with "large number". Do you mean millions of tasks per second?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A large number of anything will cause performance problems, however an awaited `Task.Delay` is one of the better approaches. It's lightweight, doesn't block a thread, and works on fairly lightweight plumbing. Its implementation is as follows:

```
public static Task Delay(int millisecondsDelay, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
  //error checking
  Task.DelayPromise delayPromise = new Task.DelayPromise(cancellationToken);
  if (cancellationToken.CanBeCanceled)
    delayPromise.Registration = cancellationToken.InternalRegisterWithoutEC((Action<object>) (state => ((Task.DelayPromise) state).Complete()), (object) delayPromise);
  if (millisecondsDelay != -1)
  {
    delayPromise.Timer = new Timer((TimerCallback) (state => ((Task.DelayPromise) state).Complete()), (object) delayPromise, millisecondsDelay, -1);
    delayPromise.Timer.KeepRootedWhileScheduled();
  }
  return (Task) delayPromise;
}
```

The `Timer` just wraps the *Win32 timer queue*, which is a *delta-queue* that fires events on the thread pool:

[Timer Queues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/windows/win32/sync/timer-queues?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

> The CreateTimerQueue function creates a queue for timers. Timers in
> this queue, known as timer-queue timers, are lightweight objects that
> enable you to specify a callback function to be called when the
> specified due time arrives.

Comment: I understand what you mean i think i should add a circuit breaker